# chrome.tabs.executeScript : Doesn't work when I tried to insert an image into specific website

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I was trying to insert an image into Amazon.com

Firstly, I verified that following code works fine in chrome console

```
insertPlace = document.getElementById("rightCol")
myImage = document.createElement("image")
myImage.src = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2c/Rotating_earth_%28large%29.gif/200px-Rotating_earth_%28large%29.gif"
myImage.onclick = function() {alert(insertImage.value)}
alert("insertImage running")
insertPlace.insertBefore(myImage)
```

However, When I assembled this code into chrome extension format, it seems that it didn't work any more. I added "tabs","","activeTab" permissions in manifest.json and the following code is background.js

```
function insertImage() {
insertPlace = document.getElementById("rightCol")
myImage = document.createElement("image")
myImage.src = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2c/Rotating_earth_%28large%29.gif/200px-Rotating_earth_%28large%29.gif"
myImage.onclick = function() {alert(insertImage.value)}
alert("insertImage running")
insertPlace.insertBefore(myImage)}
function execute () {
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, 
                   insertImage());
}
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {         
execute();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The `executeScript` function is similar to the `eval` function, in that it accepts a string of code which it executes. You are attempting to pass the results of the `insertImage` function (which is null). For the script to work, you must inject all the relevant JS code as a string:

```
function execute() {
    var script = insertImage.toString() + 'insertImage();';
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { code: script });
}
```

Comment: I believe it should be more like `chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {code: script});`.

Comment: Thank you! I successfully inserted an image into amzon.com.

Comment: Note: This method as stated in the answer only works for function declarations (`function insertImage() {...}`), not function expressions (`var insertImage = function() {...}`). A generic method that always works is to wrap the function in parentheses, then invoke it: `var script = '(' + insertImage + ')();';`.